# Is Chicago Justice accurate?

Tags: realism, chicago-justice

In the Chicago series, Chicago Justice is the fourth spinoff that shows the prosecutors from Cook County State's Attorney.

In Law and Order: SVU, which happens in Manhattan and crossovers with the Chicago series universe, traditionally the SVU team handles a case and at sometimes it goes to court, when the prosecutor takes lead. However in Chicago Justice the State's Attorney has their own team of investigation and Peter Stone (the main  Assistant State's Attorney) even interviews the victims relatives, which shows a different workflow than SVU, Chicago P.D. and other detective shows.

Is the series accurate or the writers adapted it to the series universe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes

It's common practice for prosecutors to employ their own detectives and interview witnesses for **trial** preparation.

If you want an official source..try the [**Cook County Investigations Bureau**](https://www.cookcountystatesattorney.org/investigations-bureau)

> The Investigations Bureau consists of more than 120 sworn officers who provide investigative and logistical support to Assistant State’s Attorneys in their preparation and presentation of cases. Investigators also complement and supplement local law enforcement efforts by providing them with investigative assistance, expertise and technical resources. Working with prosecutors in the Criminal Prosecutions and Special Prosecutions Bureau, Investigators also launch investigations of very specialized crimes that may not be handled by other law enforcement agencies, such as official misconduct, public integrity, election fraud, child support, and complex financial crimes.

Even the Law and Order franchise (which was also created by Dick Wolf the same as the *Chicago-X* franchise) had an, unfortunately short-lived, series featuring this preparation.

It was [***Law and Order: Trial by Jury***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_%26_Order:_Trial_by_Jury)

> The series follows Bureau Chief Tracey Kibre (Bebe Neuwirth), an Executive A.D.A. assigned to Manhattan's homicide division. Kibre's team, including Detective Lennie Briscoe (Jerry Orbach) and A.D.A. Kelly Gaffney (Amy Carlson), follows up on leads and interview witnesses, as well as participating in trials, during which both sides examine witnesses and give arguments. Similarly, the defense's preparation varies from episode to episode, running the gamut from testing arguments in front of jury focus groups to deal-making between co-defendants. Several pretrial meetings are held where some procedural issue is argued and ruled on.